# Change form in main class

Tags: c#, winforms

A form contains a progress bar which I want to change in a class,but the last line does nothing.The progress bar is set as public. Is there a way to fix this? :)

```
namespace programname
{
   static class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {    
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //splash is my form
        Splash start = new Splash();
        Application.Run(start);
        start.progressBar1.Value = 21;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Application.Run doesn't return until you close the form.

Comment: Splash start = new Splash();
start.progressBar1.Value = 21;
Application.Run(start);

Answer (score 0):

```
Splash start = new Splash();
start.progressBar1.Value = 21;
Application.Run(start);
```

Or

```
    Application.Run( new Splash() );
```

[ Splash form]

```
public void Splash_load( object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     progressBar1.Value = 21;
}
```